Error in React Native App: "Failed to create worklet error"

Warning: Error: [Reanimated] Failed to create a worklet.

I have added the plugin in the babel.config.js and i have also rebuilt the app. The error is still the same.
babel.config.js
module.exports = {

  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],

  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']

};

rebuilding the android app:
                        ./gradlew clean 
                        ./gradlew build
                        cd ..
                        npm react-native --reset-cache

I still got the same error.

Do you know what code caused it? Are you using reanimated somewhere?

i have added the plugin in babel.configjs
